# is there an equivalent of setgid bit on windows?

Tags: windows

Is there a possiblity on Windows to have an executable that always runs with the process privileges of the owner and not the one that starts the executable?

Comment: What does this have to do with information security?

Comment: @korockinout13 it sounds like it has a lot to do with it. OP: see http://serverfault.com/questions/30131/set-uid-for-windows

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan in the right context, setuid can definitely apply to security. But this question is about operating system functionality.